# generating a random value from a fix array that set as a class?

Tags: c#, asp.net

we are working on a school project (a learning game) and atm we are using a class that generate a value from a "Stack". our problem is that after the values of the stack runs out the game / program crash and stops.

i want to change it to a array with fix values and cells in it that gives me a random value each time that i address it.

right now the code is this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for CellInfoRepository
/// </summary>
public class CellProducer
{
    System.Collections.Generic.Stack<Cell> _stack = new Stack<Cell>();



    public CellProducer()
    {



        _stack.Push(new Cell { InstrumentName = "גיטרה", InstrumentFamily = 1, myPlayer = 0 });
        _stack.Push(new Cell { InstrumentName = "עוד", InstrumentFamily = 1, myPlayer = 0 });
        _stack.Push(new Cell { InstrumentName = "סיטאר", InstrumentFamily = 1, myPlayer = 0 });
        _stack.Push(new Cell { InstrumentName = "כינור", InstrumentFamily = 1, myPlayer = 0 });
        _stack.Push(new Cell { InstrumentName = "צ'לו", InstrumentFamily = 1, myPlayer = 0 });
        _stack.Push(new Cell { InstrumentName = "ויולה", InstrumentFamily = 1, myPlayer = 0 });
        _stack.Push(new Cell { InstrumentName = "נבל", InstrumentFamily = 1, myPlayer = 0 });
        _stack.Push(new Cell { InstrumentName = "בנג'ו", InstrumentFamily = 1, myPlayer = 0 });
        _stack.Push(new Cell { InstrumentName = "תופים", InstrumentFamily = 2, myPlayer = 0 });
        _stack.Push(new Cell { InstrumentName = "מצילה", InstrumentFamily = 2, myPlayer = 0 });
        _stack.Push(new Cell { InstrumentName = "שליש", InstrumentFamily = 2, myPlayer = 0 });
        _stack.Push(new Cell { InstrumentName = "קסטנייטה", InstrumentFamily = 2, myPlayer = 0 });
        _stack.Push(new Cell { InstrumentName = "פעמוניה", InstrumentFamily = 2, myPlayer = 0 });
        _stack.Push(new Cell { InstrumentName = "קסילופון", InstrumentFamily = 2, myPlayer = 0 });
        _stack.Push(new Cell { InstrumentName = "טמבורין", InstrumentFamily = 2, myPlayer = 0 });
        _stack.Push(new Cell { InstrumentName = "פעמוני רוח", InstrumentFamily = 2, myPlayer = 0 });
        _stack.Push(new Cell { InstrumentName = "קרן יער", InstrumentFamily = 3, myPlayer = 0 });
        _stack.Push(new Cell { InstrumentName = "בריטון", InstrumentFamily = 3, myPlayer = 0 });
        _stack.Push(new Cell { InstrumentName = "טרומבון", InstrumentFamily = 3, myPlayer = 0 });
        _stack.Push(new Cell { InstrumentName = "טובה", InstrumentFamily = 3, myPlayer = 0 });
        _stack.Push(new Cell { InstrumentName = "סקסופון", InstrumentFamily = 3, myPlayer = 0 });
        _stack.Push(new Cell { InstrumentName = "חליל", InstrumentFamily = 3, myPlayer = 0 });
        _stack.Push(new Cell { InstrumentName = "קלרינט", InstrumentFamily = 3, myPlayer = 0 });
        _stack.Push(new Cell { InstrumentName = "משרוקית", InstrumentFamily = 3, myPlayer = 0 });
    }

    public Cell ProduceNextCell()
    {
        return _stack.Pop();
    }
}
```

any idea how i keep the name of the class, but only change the inside for a array that generade random values?

btw, the "cell" is another class that we made, and the array should be made from him:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Cells
/// </summary>
public class Cell:Panel //מחלקת משושים
{
    protected string _instrumentName; //שם כלי הנגינה  //
    protected int _insturmentFamily; //סוג כלי הנגינה - המשפחה //
    protected int _myPlayer; //ערכים מספריים של 0 - אין שחקן - 1 ו2 לפי השחקנים

    public string InstrumentName
    {
        get
        {
            return _instrumentName;
        }

        set
        {
            _instrumentName = value;
        }
    }

    public int InstrumentFamily
    {
        get
        {
            return _insturmentFamily;
        }

        set
        {
            _insturmentFamily = value;
        }
    }

    public int myPlayer
    {
        get
        {
            return _myPlayer;
        }

        set
        {
            _myPlayer = value;
        }
    }
}

public class CellPosition // מחלקה ששומרת את מיקומי התאים
{
    private int _Column;
    private int _Row;

    public int Column
    {
        get
        {
            return _Column;
        }

        set
        {
            _Column = value;
        }
    }

    public int Row
    {
        get
        {
            return _Row;
        }

        set
        {
            _Row = value;
        }
    }
}
```

thanks for the help and sorry for all the notes in Hebrew!

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a stack instead of a List<Cell>?

Comment: we used the stack until now just to make the game work. we do know that we need to change it to some sort of array so the values we get back will be random. thats what we are trying to do atm, making an array from the cell and generate a random value of it: "        Cell[] myArry = new Cell[23];"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but i think it would work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for CellInfoRepository
/// </summary>
public class CellProducer
{
    System.Collections.Generic.List<Cell> cells = new List<Cell>();
    Random random = new Random();

    public CellProducer()
    {
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "גיטרה", InstrumentFamily = 1, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "עוד", InstrumentFamily = 1, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "סיטאר", InstrumentFamily = 1, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "כינור", InstrumentFamily = 1, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "צ'לו", InstrumentFamily = 1, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "ויולה", InstrumentFamily = 1, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "נבל", InstrumentFamily = 1, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "בנג'ו", InstrumentFamily = 1, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "תופים", InstrumentFamily = 2, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "מצילה", InstrumentFamily = 2, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "שליש", InstrumentFamily = 2, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "קסטנייטה", InstrumentFamily = 2, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "פעמוניה", InstrumentFamily = 2, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "קסילופון", InstrumentFamily = 2, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "טמבורין", InstrumentFamily = 2, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "פעמוני רוח", InstrumentFamily = 2, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "קרן יער", InstrumentFamily = 3, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "בריטון", InstrumentFamily = 3, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "טרומבון", InstrumentFamily = 3, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "טובה", InstrumentFamily = 3, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "סקסופון", InstrumentFamily = 3, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "חליל", InstrumentFamily = 3, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "קלרינט", InstrumentFamily = 3, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "משרוקית", InstrumentFamily = 3, myPlayer = 0 });
    }

    public Cell ProduceNextCell()
    {
        return cells[random.Next(cells.Count)];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a List or an array to store the Instruments. Then generate a random integer between 0 and the number of elements you have.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for CellInfoRepository
/// </summary>
public class CellProducer
{
    System.Collections.Generic.List<Cell> cells = new List<Cell>();
    int index = -1;

    public CellProducer()
    {
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "?????", InstrumentFamily = 1, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "???", InstrumentFamily = 1, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "?????", InstrumentFamily = 1, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "?????", InstrumentFamily = 1, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "?'??", InstrumentFamily = 1, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "?????", InstrumentFamily = 1, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "???", InstrumentFamily = 1, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "???'?", InstrumentFamily = 1, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "?????", InstrumentFamily = 2, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "?????", InstrumentFamily = 2, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "????", InstrumentFamily = 2, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "????????", InstrumentFamily = 2, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "???????", InstrumentFamily = 2, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "????????", InstrumentFamily = 2, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "???????", InstrumentFamily = 2, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "?????? ???", InstrumentFamily = 2, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "??? ???", InstrumentFamily = 3, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "??????", InstrumentFamily = 3, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "???????", InstrumentFamily = 3, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "????", InstrumentFamily = 3, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "???????", InstrumentFamily = 3, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "????", InstrumentFamily = 3, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "??????", InstrumentFamily = 3, myPlayer = 0 });
        cells.Add(new Cell { InstrumentName = "???????", InstrumentFamily = 3, myPlayer = 0 });
    }

    public Cell ProduceNextCell()
    {
        index++;
        if(index>cells.length){
            index = 0;
        return cells[index];
    }
}
```

Comment: thats what im trying to do :)

Comment: See Nikola Markovinović's answer below. But note, that his answer will give a random value each time. If you want a sequential list (as you have already coded) you could use the code in my now edited answer

Comment: first of all, thank you so much for the help, because its a game we want the InstrumentName to be random, different and "endless" so they could repeat forever.